# Postgres БД с 1000 схемами и по 100 таблиц в каждой схеме

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, циклы

Как создать цикл на Postgres в котором будет создаваться 1000 схем и по 100 таблиц в каждой схеме? Никак не могу найти решение, помогите! В конце должно получится schema0, schema1, ... и в каждой схеме table0, table1, table2, ...

Comment: Зачем вам это, какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Мне нужно создать тестовую БД такого плана, чтобы рассмотреть проблему pg_dump. pg_dump одной схемы будет обрабатываться долго, хочу его ускорить если получится.

Comment: создайте цикл на баше с вызовом psql

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я это могу сделать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый прямой вариант:

```sql
DO
$$
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 1000 LOOP
    EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA schema_' || i;
    FOR j IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
      EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE schema_' || i || '.table_' || j || ' (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)';
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
;
```

Будьте готовы к тому, что выполняться будет долго и что придётся
подкручивать параметры, ибо делается тут всё в одной транзакции.
Дальше — параллелизация через *Shell*
и т. д.